# my dell inspiron won't play region 1 dvd's

Tags: windows-7, dvd, dell-inspiron, regional-settings

i don't remember when i first started having this problem, but it's been a few years. i also can't remember if it's always been an issue or if i was originally able to watch dvd's on this laptop & it randomly stopped working, but here is my problem:

whenever i place a dvd in the drive, i get an error stating that it can't play region 1 dvds. at one time, the window to set the laptop's region popped up with the instruction that i needed to set the laptop's region to region 1 in order watch region 1 dvd's. so, i selected "region 1" as my region. the problem persisted. that was the first & only time i attempted to set my laptop's region.

any suggestions on how to rectify this issue?

thanks!

Comment: I see 259000 hits on a Google search for "dell inspiron dvd region". What else have you tried?

Comment: What software are you using to play these DVDs exactly?  Have you tried other alternatives to that software?

Comment: One location that item is adjustable (on some devices) is in the "Device Manager" , in there find your CD/DVD and bring up the properties for that device. There should be a Tab called DVDRegion. Usually you get only 5 changes, just so you know.  At least you could go in there and Look, see if that tab exists, and see what it claims it is set for (or not selected).  If there is no tab there, then indicate what the Name of that device is and the driver it is using.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is that the user wasn't the administrator.  Try logging in as the administrator to see if that's the problem.